# Common term for hostname and IP address?

Tags: http, uri, terminology

A simple question. Is there a generic term for hostname and IP address? I would like to call them in with one name in a UI field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use term like Server Address or Destination Server, if that helps.